# cancel file upload not working very well in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, html

Internet Explorer is causing a problem for me when it comes to cancelling a file upload but in all other browsers it is not causing any probelms when it comes to cancelling files.

Now in the other browsers, if I upload a file and then during uploading I click on the "Cancel" button, it will stop the file uploading into the server, dislay the cancel message and that is it, nothing else happens which is great.

But in interent explorer, if I upload a file and then during uploading I click on the "Cancel" button, it dislays the cancel message but then it is still uploading the file in the background, meaning the file will gt uploaded into the server and then it will dispplay the file is successfully load message, replacing the cancel message.

My question is that what in my code is causing the problem in internet explorer that it continues file uploading even though I hav cancelled the uplaod. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Below is a form where it contains a file input as well as and upload and cancel button;

```
<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_image' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' > 
 Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>
 <input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>
 <input type='reset' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' /></label>
 <iframe class='upload_target_image' name='upload_target_image' src='#' style='width:0px;height:0px;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>
```

Below is the function for the starting of the uploading of the file where it contains the cancel function inside:

```
 function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');
  sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

        $(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
                  $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow
              $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");
               jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php").done(function(data) {

        return stopImageUpload(2);
    });  

}); 

      return true;
}
```

Below is the code where after the upload is finished it displays the relevant messages:

```
      var imagecounter = 0;

function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      imagecounter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">The file was uploaded successfully</span>';      
      }
      else if (success == 2){
          result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'"> The file upload was cancelled</span>';
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+imagecounter+'">There was an error during file upload</span>';
      }


      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','hidden');
      $(sourceImageForm).find('.imagemsg').html(result);
      $(sourceImageForm).find(".fileImage").replaceWith("<input type='file' class='fileImage' name='fileImage' />");


      return true;   
}
```

Below is the imageupload.php page where it uploads the files:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


session_start();


if ($_FILES['fileImage']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $result = 0;


    if (getimagesize($_FILES['fileImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        if ((($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["fileImage"]["type"] == "image/jpg")) && ($_FILES['fileImage']['size'] > 0)) {
            if (is_file("ImageFiles/" . $_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
                $parts = explode(".", $_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
                $ext   = array_pop($parts);
                $base  = implode(".", $parts);
                $n     = 2;

                while (is_file("ImageFiles/" . $base . "_" . $n . "." . $ext))
                    $n++;
                $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base . "_" . $n . "." . $ext;

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
                $result = 1;


            }

            else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"], "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
                $result = 1;
            }

        }

    }
} else {
    echo "Upload was not successful";
}

?> 

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php
echo $result;
?>, '<?php
echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
?>');</script> 



</body> 
</html>
```

UPDATE:

Is below correct in what you are stating:

```
//startImageUpload

    function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

      $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');
      sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

            $(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
        $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow
        $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");
         $request = $.ajax("cancelimage.php").done(function(data) {

            return stopImageUpload(2);

        });  

    }); 

          return true;
    }

//imageClickHandler

 function imageClickHandler(imageuploadform){ 
      if(imageValidation(imageuploadform)){ 
          window.lastUploadImageIndex = $('.imageuploadform').index(imageuploadform); 
          return startImageUpload(imageuploadform); 
          $request.abort()
      } 
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure it actually continues uploading, or is it the progress bar not stopping that makes you think so? We had the exact same problem, and it was an issue with the jquery dialog giving an error that would keep the bar running...

Comment: @mplungjan It is continuing the uploading, I cancel the file yet it still does the uploading in the background and uploads file into server and changes display to state upload is successful

Comment: Ah, you have your own cancel. If you had used the system dialog it would not continue I believe

Comment: Can you do `$request = $.ajax(...)` then you can try `$request.abort()`

Comment: @mplungjan, I included an update at bottom of question where it shows latest version of the start image upload function and the cancel button function with your request idea, is the code in my update correct in what you have mentioned?

Comment: No. 1) Nothing is executed after a return. The cancel needs to be before the return 2) you need to cancel the IMAGE upload, not the CANCELIMAGEUPLOAD. you are not showing the code that uploads the image i.e. imageclickhandler

Comment: @mplungjan I included the imageclickhandler function in the update as well. Can't believe I forgot to include that. Are you ok if you don't mind to copy and [aste my update and in your answer show how I should code it. I had another go in the update but doubt I got it correct, still little bit confused on trying to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I assumed wrongly that you were using ajax to upload the image. 
Now I see the complete code I realise you are simply allowing the form to submit and the ajax is only to communicate with the php that receives the cancel. That means that you cannot use ajax abort to cancel the upload. What you can do instead is to replace the iframe contents with the cancelimage.php. I have not tested this

```
//startImageUpload

function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_cancel').css('visibility','visible');

  sourceImageForm = imageuploadform; // not sure what this does

  $(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {

    $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow; // not sure what this is doing....

    $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").on("load",function() {
      stopImageUpload(2);
    }).attr("src", "cancelimage.php")

  }); 

  return true;
}

//imageClickHandler

function imageClickHandler(imageuploadform){ 
  if(imageValidation(imageuploadform)){ 
      window.lastUploadImageIndex = $('.imageuploadform').index(imageuploadform); 
      return startImageUpload(imageuploadform); 
  } 
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have upvoted because you have put some effort in your answer obviously, I will test it, mess around with it and let you know the outcome. fingers cross it works :)

Comment: It has worked perfectly in internet explorer and other browsers. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just one little quick question btw, when I include this, then when I successfully upload a file it displays the message that file upload is cnacelled, obviously this is the wrong message when file is uploaded successfully but is there something additional I need to add in order to get the correct upload successfull message to appear when file upload is successful?

Comment: That is your code. Call  stopImageUpload(1); instead of (2) when success